# How to pause my code vuetify with breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, breakpoints

The case like this :

[image]

My code in the console like that. So I found it hard to make a `breakpoint`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

just use **debugger;** in your javascript code, then open browser debugger console and trigger the code, so automatically debug pointer will point at your exact position of code.

for more details [read](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/debugging-in-javascript/)

Comment: I checked this on the production server. where it's been minified. and I'm having trouble making a breakpoint.

Comment: it is not allowed in production, it is debugging so worked for development mode